# Subdomain forwarding to main domain on ssl requests only

Tags: apache, ssl, virtualhost, httpd.conf

Below is a copy of my ssl.conf that I edited to remove any identifying information.

Currently, we have a wild card SSL cert, and multiple sub domains that we plan to host with this certificate. [Apache confirms this should be possible](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHosts)

Right now, domain 2 is forwarding to www, but I can;t figure out why. In an effort to narrow it down, I removed the www virtualhost from the file altogether and redeployed.
the redirect still happened (and as the only vhost, it loaded the domain2 file structure)

I can't figure out where this redirect is happening. is it possible that there is an issue with the certificate? (I confirmed that the common name on the certificate is *.example.com)

```
Listen ip-of-server:443

LoadModule ssl_module   modules/mod_ssl.so

SSLPassPhraseDialog     builtin
AcceptMutex             flock
SSLSessionCache         shmcb:/var/cache/mod_ssl/scache(512000)
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300
SSLMutex                default
SSLRandomSeed           startup /dev/urandom  256
SSLRandomSeed           connect builtin

NameVirtualHost ip-of-server:443

<VirtualHost ip-of-server:443>
        SSLEngine on
        SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck on

        SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP

SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache/ssl/STAR.example.com.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/example.com.key

        ServerName      "domain2.example.com"
        DocumentRoot    "/srv/www/domain2.example.com/public_html"

        CustomLog       "/srv/www/domain2.example.com/logs/access.log" combined
        ErrorLog        "/srv/www/domain2.example.com/logs/error.log"

        <Directory /var/www/html>
                AllowOverride none

                Order Allow,Deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost ip-of-server:443>
        SSLEngine on
        SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck on

        SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP

SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache/ssl/STAR.example.com.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/example.com.key

        ServerName      "www.example.com"
        DocumentRoot    "/srv/www/www.example.com/public_html"

        CustomLog       "/srv/www/www.example.com/logs/access.log" combined
        ErrorLog        "/srv/www/www.example.com/logs/error.log"

        <Directory /var/www/html>
                AllowOverride none

                Order Allow,Deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: `NameVirtualHost` has been deprecated: https://devdocs.io/apache_http_server/mod/core#namevirtualhost

Comment: Yea, I had read that previously. I left it in as a desperate hope that maybe I was on an old version of apache that needed it.

Comment: You could've done `sudo apachectl -V` (or `-v` whichever is applicable for version)

Comment: There is no redirect or rewrite in domain2, so touching anything in another virtualhost is a futile attempt. Remove your browsers cache, or try `curl -I https://domain2.example.com` and make sure it is your server replying and not something else, and if there is a redirect, try to identify from the headers where the redirect is coming from, but clearly it is not in what we see in the config.

Comment: What would Sam Do?

Comment: Yea, its very clear its not something in the config. I know its not in my htaccess. I know the browser is not caching. I know its going to my server (changing the config reflects in browser) So I am running out of places that would be redirecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out at some point we had a 301 redirect that pointed domain2 to www. Google chrome had cached that 301. disabling cache with devtools open caused page to load correctly over ssl.